# php variable inside a variable in a while query

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable:

```
$category =  3;

$data = MY SQL QUERY....

while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array( $data)) 
    {   echo $data2['$category'] ; }
```

I want to get the sql value of `echo $data2['3'];`  by using the vairable `$category` ...

is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct but you have to remove the single quotes

```
{   echo $data2['$category'] ; }
```

should be changed to

```
{   echo $data2[$category] ; }
```